# SQL select top 101

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange situation with a select. I've noticed that when I select  top 100, a record is not returning from the database, but when doing top 101 the record appears on position 41.

The query is like this:

```
select top 100 GroupId, count(HouseId)
from House h
group by h.GroupId
order by max([DateCreated]) desc
```

From all discussions about top 100 vs top 101 I've noticed that everybody is saying that the top 101 is using another algorithm and we can have a speed problem, but my problem is not about this. With top 100 I'm missing a record that should appear at index 41. Has anybody noticed something like this?

Comment: what do you mean, "the record appears on Position 41"? Do you mean row 41? In your query, there is no ordering guaranteed.  The ORDER BY here just tells SQL-Server which rows to select for the TOP-Clause

Comment: @CPMunich - `Order by` present

Comment: @Indian there is an order by clause but it is pointless because it is ordering by an aggregate. This is like saying "order by 'asdf'". In other words, the order by here does nothing to guarantee order.

Comment: @SeanLange Isn't it actually ordering by a grouped aggregate? so, it wouldn't actually be the same as `"order by 'asdf' "`

Comment: @SeanLange What's wrong with ORDER BY on an aggregate function?

Comment: @BaconBits Nothing. I just need more coffee.

Comment: @SeanLange I think my [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5012a/3) is correct. Or maybe I'll just go make some more coffee myself.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu it is I that needs more coffee. I would delete my previous horribly incorrect comment but it would leave a strange hole in the comments.

Comment: @SeanLange Maybe coffee is not the solution, maybe a pint/beer/lager/brew and an end of day would be better (if it's after 5:00 PM in your timezone).

Comment: LOL. I wish it was that late but it still before lunch here...although a pint always sounds good. :)

Answer (score 1):

when you use

```
order by max([DateCreated]) desc
```

it is calculated before TOP in the query.
Every time you include one more record, max([DateCreated]) re-positions this new record according to its value among all other records.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this makes sense to me is if you have a lot of records with the same `max([DateCreated])`.  What do you get when you run this:

```
select top 100 with ties GroupId, count(HouseId)
from House h
group by h.GroupId
order by max([DateCreated]) desc
```

If you get more than 100 records, then the database was just picking the first 100 rows it got to after sorting the result set.  When you changed it to `TOP 101`, another row was added and it probably ended up at row 41 due to clustered indexes or other query engine implementation details that might affect row order when the query isn't deterministic.